# Issue, non-static/non-global variable being shared between two objects?

Tags: python, class, object, parent

It would appear that two objects are sharing the same non-static/non-global variable and I am confused how that is possible, see below:

```
class Pop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 2
        self.w = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        self.w_min = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.w_max = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    def populate(self, __run):
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.varients.append(Varient(self))
            for x in range(len(self.varients[i].w)):
                self.varients[i].w[x] = randint(self.varients[i].w_min[x] * 100,
                                                        self.varients[i].w_max[x] * 100) / 100
                    else:
                        self.varients[i].w[x] = randint(self.varients[i].w_min[x] * 100,
                                                        self.varients[i].w_max[x] * 100) / 100
            print(self.varients[i].w)
        print(self.varients[0].w)
        print(self.varients[1].w)
        for x in range(len(self.varients[1].w)):
            self.varients[1].w[x] = 1
        print(self.varients[0].w)
        print(self.varients[1].w)


class Varient(Pop):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.w = parent.w
        self.w_min = parent.w_min
        self.w_max = parent.w_max
```

This is the output I see:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.86, 0.685, 0.925, 0.735, 0.35, 0.825, 0.31, 0.62, 0.71, 0.88]
[1.0, 1.0, 0.565, 0.575, 0.95, 0.405, 0.605, 0.48, 0.42, 0.445, 0.745, 0.41]
[1.0, 1.0, 0.565, 0.575, 0.95, 0.405, 0.605, 0.48, 0.42, 0.445, 0.745, 0.41]
[1.0, 1.0, 0.565, 0.575, 0.95, 0.405, 0.605, 0.48, 0.42, 0.445, 0.745, 0.41]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

When I change the value of "w" for object "self.varients[1]" it somehow changes the value of "self.varients[0]". If I was passing pointers arround this would make sense to me, but I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Lists are mutable if thats the actual problem.

Comment: This code is not valid syntax (the indentation is off), nor is there a way to run it to see the problem ourselves. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `self.w = parent.w` doesn't make a new list. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: What you did is `self.w = parent.w`. That means that `self.w` is now another reference for the same object `parent.w` references. So yes, you just created another name for the exact same object. You need to create a copy. This can be done a few different ways: `parent.w[:]`, `parent.w.copy()`, `list(parent.w)`, etc.

Comment: I added another duplicate that explains pass by assignment.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, but if you are familiar with pointers, you can think of all Python variables as Python object pointers. I second the recommendation to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html